# Upgrade windows 10 to pro with 7 pro oem key

Tags: windows-10, oem

I have a few computers with Windows 8/8.1 Home edition that need to be upgraded to professional editions of Windows in order to join a newly created company domain. I have a couple unused Windows 7 Pro OEM kits, so in theory I could do a clean install to convert them to 7 pro (and I don't think my users would complain, except for the time that takes and the hassle needed to keep their files).

However, I've learned that after upgrading to Windows 10 for free, as long as you bring it up to update 1511, you can use Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 keys to upgrade to Windows 10 pro, which I figure might be a little quicker at least and puts off end of life that much longer... but I can't find anything specifically stating if this use-case works with the key from an OEM Kit. I also don't really know much about OEM software, so even if this works I'm not sure if there would be disadvantages that might make purchasing new keys worth the money.

So, in short: Does the option to upgrade Windows 10 Home to Professional using a Windows 7 Pro key work if that key is OEM, and are there any disadvantages to this over purchasing a retail key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 2):

It will work no problem. I did it many times on my clients' machines.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't (or you must not) use a OEM license in a different PC. Maybe is possible make some workaround, but I don't believe it's good idea take the risk due those are company resources.
[OEM FAQ here](https://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx).

Little longer answer:
For jump from Windows 7/8/8.1 Home to Pro you can:

1. Upgrade to 10 Home
2. Change the product key to VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T and there will start a upgrade process to Pro edition. IMPORTANT! This key won't activate the OS!!
3. After finished the upgrade process, you will have a Windows 10 Pro ready. Now change the key. You will need a Key for 7/8/8.1 Pro edition. We always use retail licenses, so, I don't know how will work with OEM, but in any case, that's ilegal.
   [more here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/upgrade-windows-10-pro]

The other way: clean Windows 10 Pro install

From my experience, the process of upgrade from 7/8/8.1 to 10, and after from Home to Pro, is not exactly the 'faster' way. I didn't take the time with the swatch, but I can tell you there won't be a big different from a fresh install. The first step in the upgrade is check for updates in the actual OS, and just that will take few longs minutes. Plus, the process need more interaction with the user than making a clean installation.

Just this week I upgraded few workstations. We use KAV Endpoint Security and is necessary uninstall it before upgrade. After I finish the whole process with the first PC, I decided make a clean install for the rest of them.

In the case you decide to upgrade, I highly recommend you use a DVD or a USB memory, because the online upgrade will make the process incredible slowly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, you're saying that each OEM license is only valid for one computer, correct? These OEM kits are currently unopened with unbroken seals, so that shouldn't be a problem as far as using them here. It's just a matter of if they would work, and if maybe there's a reason we shouldn't use them even if they haven't been used before, and spend the money for new retail keys instead?

Comment: I'm not specialist in licenses :) but from OEM I understand is ONLY possible use it in the PC where came installed, even if there is a major hardware change, won't will work. Are you sure what you have is OEM? because I think OEM licenses always come pre-installed in new computers. Maybe I'm wrong ...
In any case, if you have the license in the hand, try it and let me know ;)

Comment: I just found this interesting article about Windows license: http://www.zdnet.com/article/what-microsoft-wont-tell-you-about-windows-7-licensing/